# Why enging.connect() not equal session.connection() in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

print db.engine.connect()
print db.session.connection()
# <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7fb9daf01ad0>
# <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x7fb9da0edcd0>
print db.engine.connect().connection.connection
print db.session.connection().connection.connection
# <_mysql.connection open to '*' at 2b30c30>
# <_mysql.connection open to '*' at 2b1ab80>
```

Why the engine.connect() is not equal session.connection()? This code use Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Because they are separate connection objects handling separate connections.

Comment: @ilja-everilä Is there a way to make them equal?

Comment: Pass the connection object from `engine.connect()` as the bind to a session: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#session-external-transaction. But the real question is why? Calling [`Engine.connect()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.connect) either creates a new connection, or picks one available in the current pool. Sessions usually use engines as binds and fetch their connections from them.

Comment: Why does not the session pick the connection created by `engine.connect()`, which is available and has not been used yet.

Comment: The first `Connection` object facade goes away after the 1st statement has been executed. Your session is using another facade. Depending on what you've done *before* the code you've presented, these facades might be using the same underlying DB-API connection, or not. Try printing `print db.engine.connect().connection.connection` and `print db.session.connection().connection.connection` in order to inspect the underlying DB-API connections. And still: why do you need this? What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Exactly: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm writing tests for my flask app. I used `db.engine` to load data on setup and `rollback` on `teardown`. But my flask code uses `session` to operate the database. I found that data inserted by `db.engine` can't be seen by `sessin.query` , and I finally find the reason is that they used different connections. So I'm curious about why they do not use the same connection?

Comment: The pool might rotate the DB-API connections, or some such. But that does not matter. You should organize your code so that you can use the pattern described in the linked material: ["Joining a Session into an External Transaction (such as for test suites)"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#session-external-transaction). This Q/A from before discusses using that in flask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374005/flask-sqlalchemy-how-do-sessions-work-with-multiple-databases.

Comment: And here's a post that explains how to use pytest fixtures to handle all that: http://alexmic.net/flask-sqlalchemy-pytest/