# Dynamically create flask sqlalchemy database connection using user inputs

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I was wondering if it was possible to create the SqlAlchemy database URI using inputs passed in by the user. For example, having input text fields in which the user will have to input the parameters needed to create the database uri. Only then will the connection be established and the user can then access the data within the database.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is possible. But you need to manage database connections without `flask-sqlalchemy`.

You need a storage for database engines and a route for updating it. Database engines are created in this route and tested if they are actually functional by executing simple request. Database URI is saved to the user session to use it afterwards:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template, request, session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.exc import OperationalError

ENGINES = {}

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/set_database_uri", methods=("GET", "POST"))
def set_database_uri():
    if request.method == "POST":
        database_uri = request.form["database_uri"]
        if database_uri not in ENGINES:
            engine = create_engine(database_uri)
            try:
                engine.execute("SELECT 1")
            except OperationalError:
                return Response("Invalid database URI", 400)
            ENGINES[database_uri] = engine
        session["database_uri"] = database_uri
    return render_template("database_uri.html")
```

These engines can be used to produce SQLAlchemy sessions to make the required database operations:

```
from flask import redirect, session, url_for
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

@app.route("/records")
def get_records():
    if "database_uri" not in session:
        return redirect(url_for("set_database_uri"))

    db_session = Session(session["database_uri"])
    records = db_session.query(Record).all()
    db_session.close()

    return render_template("records.html", records=records)
```

Though technically possible it is not recommended to use this approach. It may lead to serious security vulnerability as the potential user can create a database connection to any database available from the application host.

However it may be useful if you are making some sort of database administration interface.

Answer (score 0):

I just stacked with the same issue, I fixed it like this.

config part:

```html
from contextlib import contextmanager

from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from greenwater_app import app


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db/database1.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_BINDS'] = {
    'database2': 'sqlite:///db/database2.db'
}
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

migrate = Migrate(app, db, compare_type=True)


@contextmanager
def session_scope(bind='default'):
    """Provide a transactional scope around a series of operations."""

    if bind != 'default':
        s = db.create_scoped_session(options={'bind': db.get_engine(db.get_app(), bind)})
    else:
        s = db.session

    s.expire_on_commit = False
    try:
        yield s
        s.commit()
    except:
        s.rollback()
        raise
    finally:
        s.close()
```

then, we can add "**bind_key**" as "database2" in Class definition to use "database2". just like this.
https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/binds/

```html
class User(db.Model, BaseModelMixin):
    __bind_key__ = "database2"
    __tablename__ = "user"
```

if we want to a special session, we can do like this.

```html
sql = 'select * from user'
with session_scope(bind='database2') as s:
    res = s.execute(sql).fetchall()
    print([dict(r) for r in res])

with session_scope() as s:
    res = s.execute(sql).fetchall()
    print([dict(r) for r in res])
```

session_scope(bind='database2') will get a session for database2.